# How to get the name of a Wikidata item within wikicode?

Tags: mediawiki, wikidata

Let's say I have a Wikidata item QID `Q19675`, and want to get the name of that item in Spanish within the wikicode of an unrelated [Mediawiki](http://mediawiki.org/) page.

While getting a property like `P281 postal code` is easy (just write `{{#property:P281|from=Q19675}}`), how to get the name, which for some reason is not a normal [property](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:List_of_properties/Generic)?

[image: Wikidata item name]

Unlike [this question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/5248/how-to-get-the-name-of-a-wikidata-item), this time I am **not looking for a REST API, but for a Mediawiki wikicode expression**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the Lua function `mw.wikibase.label`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Wikibase_Client/Lua#mw.wikibase.label) to get the label in the local language. If you're on a wiki that has a copy of [the Wikidata template `Label`](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Template:Label) (e.g. the English Wikipedia), you can use that directly: `{{label|Q19675}}`.

If you want the label in a language other than local, use [`mw.wikibase.entity:getLabel`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Wikibase_Client/Lua#mw.wikibase.entity:getLabel).

Comment: This works for English, thanks! Too bad `{{label|Q19675|es}}` does not work yet... The [template documentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Label) actually says "*The language code parameter does not work yet.*" How to use `mw.wikibase.entity:getLabel` directly within the wikicode?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I don't think you can. The common approach is what `label` does: create a Lua `Module` that does what you want, then create a `Template` that `{{#invoke}}`s it and use that from wikicode.